# Almost 12 seconds delay in getting the connection from a remote database on a network

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection, derby

I have a Java Swing application which access a remote database on a local network.
The code i used is as follow:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
conn=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://10.137.242.182:1527/C:/Users/545404/.netbeans-derby/deviceapp");
return conn;
```

It is working fine when I access the DB from the same machine on which the Derby Server is running.

But when I use it form other systems on the local network.
It is having a delay of around 10-12 seconds to get the connection.

Please suggest a proper way of accessing DB faster on a local network.

Comment: Do you get the same delay when you restart the client? (I'm wondering whether the server in question is paging back into memory from disk, or something like that.) Also, if you use WireShark to see what's happening at the network level, that may give some indication.

Comment: Restarting the client is not fixing the problem

Comment: please reply whether is this the proper way to access a DB over a network

Comment: Well I've never used Derby, but I've suggested an approach to diagnosing it further: look at what's happening on the network. It does look odd that you're effectively passing a filename as the database name. Maybe that's the "right" thing to do, but it definitely looks odd.

Comment: ya..i know..
in derby there was two ways of connecting to DB.
jdbc:derby://10.137.242.182:1527/deviceapp.
or
jdbc:derby://10.137.242.182:1527/C:/Users/545404/.netbeans-derby/deviceapp

the first one was not working..hence i tried for the second one..

Comment: Okay, well I would go back to trying to get the first one working - it sounds like it may well be a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

My Derby clients connect to my server over my local network in just milliseconds.

There must be some strange networking issues that are causing this delay. Long multi-second delays like this are generally caused by network issues such as DNS configuration, firewalls, etc.

Did you take Jon Skeet's advice to use WireShark to examine your network activity? What does WireShark show about the network access?